# Why is MoGenerator falling afoul of ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, mogenerator

My command line (a build phase) for MoGen is

```
mogenerator -m PT1/Data/DataModel.xcdatamodeld -O PT1/Data -–template-var arc=true
```

This is supposed to work for ARC. However in the machine classes I get something like

```
extern const struct ClientInfoAttributes {
    NSString *accountNumber;
    ...
} ClientInfoAttributes;
```

This gives the error "ARC forbids Objective-C objects in struct". Presumably I have made some kind of mistake here. Can anybody point out my problem?

I am working with the iOS7 and XCode 5 beta, but this does not seem to be related to that. It may be relevant though.

-Bob

Comment: I believe you need two dashes before template-var, unless that's a typo in your question.

Comment: I don't know anything about MoGenerator but the error is clear. Under ARC, you are not allowed to create a `struct` that has object pointers. Your `ClientInfoAttributes` struct has a field with a pointer to `NSString`. Under ARC, a `struct` can only have non-object fields.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mogenerator and ARC in XCode 4.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192914/mogenerator-and-arc-in-xcode-4-6)

Comment: The question is closely related to the one you quote, but that one was not answered adequately IMHO.

Comment: I added the second "-" and it did not help. This came from a typo in this very helpful page, http://raptureinvenice.com/getting-started-with-mogenerator/. I contacted him and the typo should be corrected now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I WAS using the correct option to mogenerator for ARC. It is --template-var arc=true as you see above in my original question. However, I copied the command line from this blog entry, raptureinvenice.com/getting-started-with-mogenerator. In this entry the interwebs software had changed the author's "--" to an long dash or m-dash. When I copied and pasted I got a dash that looked right but was not. The mogen software does not currently flag this as an error. It just silently ignores it.

When I finally retyped the -- from scratch it worked correctly. Mogen uses __unsafe_unretained  to prevent the compiler errors.

The blog author has already fixed the blog entry and I have lodged an issue with the mogen project to report errors of this type in the future.

Comment: Had to wait 20 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the order matters. Use

> mogenerator --template-var arc=true -m PT1/Data/DataModel.xcdatamodeld -O PT1/Data

---

About the error, it is self-explanatory

> ARC forbids Objective-C objects in struct

As explained in the [clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership-qualified-fields-of-structs-and-unions)

> ### 4.3.5 Ownership-qualified fields of structs and unions
>
> A program is ill-formed if it declares a member of a C struct or union to have a nontrivially ownership-qualified type.
>
> #### Rationale
>
> The resulting type would be non-POD in the C++ sense, but C does not give us very good language tools for managing the lifetime of aggregates, so it is more convenient to simply forbid them. It is still possible to manage this with a `void*` or an `__unsafe_unretained` object.

So, as the documentation suggests, the quick and dirty solution for this is to declare the object as `__unsafe_unretained`. Something like:

```
extern const struct ClientInfoAttributes {
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *accountNumber;
    ...
} ClientInfoAttributes;
```

Anyway beware since from now on you have to take care of memory management for such object.

Comment: The order did not matter. I tried that early on. The clang error was obvious from the start. It was a mogenerator issue. See my answer.